# How to remove unsafety in a conditional Clingo rule?

Tags: conditional-statements, clingo

I would like to define the set of nodes in a directed graph reachable from all nodes in a given set of start nodes in Clingo. To my understanding, this can be done via *conditions* in a rule body: in a rule

```
p(X) :- q(X) : r(X).
```

a conjunction of rules `q(a)` is dynamically generated in the body of `p/1` for grounded facts `a`, for which the rule `r(a)` also holds. Now for some reason, the following set of rules results in an "unsafe" variable `X` being discovered on the last line:

```
% Test case

arc(1,4). arc(2,4). arc(3,5). arc(4,1). arc(4,2). arc(4,3).
start(1). start(4). start(5).

% Define a path inductively, with the base case being path of length 1:

path(A, B) :- arc(A, B).
path(A, B) :- arc(A, X), arc(X, B).
path(A, B) :- arc(A, X), path(X, Y), arc(Y, B).

% A node X is simply reachable/1, if there is a possibly empty path to it
% from a start node or reachable/2 from A, if there is a path to it from A:

reachable(X) :- start(X).
reachable(X) :- start(A), path(A, X).
reachable(X, A) :- path(A, X).

% Predicate all_reach defined by the reachable relation:

all_reach(X) :- reachable(X, A) : start(A).
```

I wanted to ask, what is meant by an "unsafe" variable, and how might I amend this situation? One source claims that *an unsafe variable is a variable, which appears in the head of a rule but not in the body*, which makes sense as the symbols `:-` denote a reverse implication. However, this does not seem to be the case here, so I'm confused.

Could it be that there might not be a grounded fact `a` for which `start(a)` holds, and hence the body of the implication or rule becomes empty, causing the unsafety. Is that it? Is there a standard way of avoiding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that there wasn't a positive rule in the body of `all_reach/1` that was satisfied for at least some grounded instance of `X`. Adding the lines

```
% Project nodes from arcs

node(X) :- arc(X,Y).
node(Y) :- arc(X,Y).
```

and reformulating the `all_reach/1` rule as

```
all_reach(X) :- reachable(X, A) : start(A); node(X).
```

solved the issue. The desired conjunction

```
∧[i=1 → ∞] reachable(d, s[i])
```

for all start nodes `s[i]` and destination nodes `d` is then generated as the
body of `allreach/1`.

In other words, when using conditionals in the body `b/m` of a rule `r/n`,
there must still be a predicate `p` in `b` that is *unconditionally* grounded
for any variables present in the head of the rule. Otherwise we might end up
with an ambiguity or an ever-expanding rule during grounding, which is unsafe.